# Different user has different activity on Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

After different user login, I want to redirect him to different activity. For example, after student login I want to open StudentActivity, after teacher login I want TeacherActivity... I have exactly one Teacher, others are students.
This is my code:

```
 // Parse.com Login Setup
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
            if (parseUser != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (username.equals("TEACHER_USERNAME")){
                    // here goes Intent to open TeacherActivity
                } else {
                        // here goes Intent to open StudentActivity
                       }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check your username and password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This work for me but is there another/better and more secure way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more of a database-schema question than an actual android parse question.  One way would be this:  add a column to the _User table called userType.  When a teacher or student signs up, fill this column with the value of either "teacher" or "student".  Then, when the user logs in, inside the if-statement for successful login, check the userType column for a value - if this value equals "teacher", go to TeacherActivity, if this value equals "student", go to StudentActivity